# Polars: How to include all possible values of an Enum type in results of a df.group_by

Tags: python-polars

Given a DataFrame representing "cut" intervals

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 5, 6, 10, 12, 45]}).with_columns(
    pl.col("a").cut(range(0, 100, 10)).alias("cut_a")
)
```

```
 ┌─────┬──────────┐
 │ a   ┆ cut_a    │
 │ --- ┆ ---      │
 │ i64 ┆ cat      │
 ╞═════╪══════════╡
 │ 1   ┆ (0, 10]  │
 │ 5   ┆ (0, 10]  │
 │ 6   ┆ (0, 10]  │
 │ 10  ┆ (0, 10]  │
 │ 12  ┆ (10, 20] │
 │ 45  ┆ (40, 50] │
 └─────┴──────────┘
```

I do a group_by to count the values in each bin:

```py
df.group_by("cut_a").agg(pl.len())
```

```
┌──────────┬─────┐
│ cut_a    ┆ len │
│ ---      ┆ --- │
│ cat      ┆ u32 │
╞══════════╪═════╡
│ (0, 10]  ┆ 4   │
│ (10, 20] ┆ 1   │
│ (40, 50] ┆ 1   │
└──────────┴─────┘
```

And here is my question...In the result, I need to include all possible cut groups, with null for groups that are not included in the original DataFrame. I'm looking for something like this...

```
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ cut_a     ┆ len  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ (0, 10]   ┆ 4    │
│ (10, 20]  ┆ 1    │
│ (20, 30]  ┆ null │
│ (30, 40]  ┆ null │
│ (40, 50]  ┆ 1    │
│ (50, 60]  ┆ null │
│ (60, 70]  ┆ null │
│ (70, 80]  ┆ null │
│ (80, 90]  ┆ null │
│ (90, 100] ┆ null │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's take your starting point and rewrite it as

```
cut_a=0
cut_b=100
cut_c=10
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 5, 6, 10, 12, 45]}).with_columns(
    pl.col("a").cut(range(cut_a, cut_b, cut_c)).alias("cut_a")
)
```

then we can do...

```py
a_bins = pl.Enum(
    pl.Series(range(cut_a+cut_c,cut_b+cut_c,cut_c))
    .cut(range(cut_a,cut_b+cut_c,cut_c))
    .cat.get_categories()
)

df=df.with_columns(
    cut_a=pl.col('cut_a').cast(a_bins)
    )

df.select(
    pl.col('cut_a').cat.get_categories().cast(a_bins)
).join(
    df.group_by('cut_a').len(),
    on='cut_a',
    how='left'
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 2)
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ cut_a     ┆ len  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ enum      ┆ u32  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ (0, 10]   ┆ 4    │
│ (10, 20]  ┆ 1    │
│ (20, 30]  ┆ null │
│ (30, 40]  ┆ null │
│ (40, 50]  ┆ 1    │
│ (50, 60]  ┆ null │
│ (60, 70]  ┆ null │
│ (70, 80]  ┆ null │
│ (80, 90]  ┆ null │
│ (90, 100] ┆ null │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: I just temporarily fixed up your answer to match the output - hope that's alright. `.get_categories()` returns `str` and it seems like there is no way to get the enum type back without an explicit cast. Maybe you know a better way?

Comment: it seems to me that this answer is incomplete, what is `a_bins`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is an easier/appropriate way to do this in Polars, but here is my initial approach...

1. Create an Enum type for all possible values of the cut bin intervals.
2. Create DataFrame with cut intervals.
3. Do the group_by operation.
4. Convert the Enum categories to a DataFrame and join to the original DataFrame after the group_by operation.

```py
import polars as pl

a_bins = pl.Enum(
    pl.Series("a_bins", range(1, 100))
    .cut(range(0, 101, 10))
    .unique(maintain_order=True)
    .set_sorted()
    .sort()
    .cast(str)
)


df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 5, 6, 10, 12, 45]}).with_columns(
    pl.col("a").cut(range(0, 100, 10)).cast(a_bins).alias("cut_a")
)


result = (
    df.group_by(pl.col("cut_a"))
    .agg(pl.len())
    .join(
        pl.DataFrame({"cut_a": a_bins.categories.cast(a_bins)}),
        on="cut_a",
        how="outer_coalesce",
    )
)

print(result)
```

```
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ cut_a     ┆ len  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ enum      ┆ u32  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ (0, 10]   ┆ 4    │
│ (10, 20]  ┆ 1    │
│ (20, 30]  ┆ null │
│ (30, 40]  ┆ null │
│ (40, 50]  ┆ 1    │
│ (50, 60]  ┆ null │
│ (60, 70]  ┆ null │
│ (70, 80]  ┆ null │
│ (80, 90]  ┆ null │
│ (90, 100] ┆ null │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: I think what @DeanMacGregor was trying to show was that if the categories come first, it's a left-join: `a_bins.categories.cast(a_bins).to_frame("a_cut").join(df.group_by("cut_a").len(), on="cut_a", how="left")` - it does seem like there should be a simpler way than having to re-cast again though.

Answer (score 1):

Logical way would be to create a separate DataFrame with column including all possible intervals you need and then use [`join`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html) to add count column:

```py
a_cat = (
    pl.Series(range(1, 100, 10))
    .cut(range(0, 101, 10))
)

a_cat.to_frame("cut_a").join(
   df.group_by("cut_a").len(),
   on="cut_a", 
   how="left"
)

┌───────────┬──────┐
│ cut_a     ┆ len  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ cat       ┆ u32  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ (0, 10]   ┆ 4    │
│ (10, 20]  ┆ 1    │
│ (20, 30]  ┆ null │
│ (30, 40]  ┆ null │
│ (40, 50]  ┆ 1    │
│ (50, 60]  ┆ null │
│ (60, 70]  ┆ null │
│ (70, 80]  ┆ null │
│ (80, 90]  ┆ null │
│ (90, 100] ┆ null │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

The problem with this approach is that [`Categorical`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#categorical-type) data type is local, so there will be expensive recoding happening during join. This is the warning you'll see if you try the code above:

> CategoricalRemappingWarning: Local categoricals have different
> encodings, expensive re-encoding is done to perform this merge
> operation. Consider using a StringCache or an Enum type if the
> categories are known in advance

In your case, you know all the 'buckets' in advance. In this case, it would be preferrable to use [`Enum`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#enum-type) data type.

```py
a_cat = pl.Enum(
    pl.Series(range(1, 100, 10))
    .cut(range(0, 101, 10))
    .cast(str)
)

df = df.with_columns(pl.col("cut_a").cast(a_cat).alias("cut_a"))

a_cat.categories.cast(a_cat).to_frame("cut_a").join(
   df.group_by("cut_a").len(),
   on="cut_a", 
   how="left"
)

┌───────────┬──────┐
│ cut_a     ┆ len  │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ cat       ┆ u32  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ (0, 10]   ┆ 4    │
│ (10, 20]  ┆ 1    │
│ (20, 30]  ┆ null │
│ (30, 40]  ┆ null │
│ (40, 50]  ┆ 1    │
│ (50, 60]  ┆ null │
│ (60, 70]  ┆ null │
│ (70, 80]  ┆ null │
│ (80, 90]  ┆ null │
│ (90, 100] ┆ null │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

Lastly, in your case you could've probably just use the cut-off point instead of categorical data:

```py
a_cat = pl.Series(range(0, 11))

df = df.with_columns(cut_a = (pl.col("a") - 1) // 10)

a_cat.to_frame("cut_a").join(
    df.group_by("cut_a").len(),
    on="cut_a",
    how="left"
)

┌───────┬──────┐
│ cut_a ┆ len  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64   ┆ u32  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 4    │
│ 1     ┆ 1    │
│ 2     ┆ null │
│ 3     ┆ null │
│ 4     ┆ 1    │
│ 5     ┆ null │
│ 6     ┆ null │
│ 7     ┆ null │
│ 8     ┆ null │
│ 9     ┆ null │
│ 10    ┆ null │
└───────┴──────┘
```